# To open lrzip-compressed in Debian 8.1

Tags: linux, debian, compression, tar, sage

I downloaded the SageMath jessie package [here](ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/unix/misc/sage/linux/64bit/index.html) but I cannot open it. 
I get the warning in ArchiveManager

```
Could not open this file type
There is no command installed for Tar archive (lrzip-compressed) files.
Do you want to search for a command to open this file?
```

so I click search the missing `lrzip-compressed` thing but I get

[image]

### Following @SamuelLelièvre's answer by two ways

Installing `lrzip` in Debian 8.1 and trying to open the package with `Archive Manager` gives

[image]

where you see that the error message changed after installing the command, which is strange. 
Doing then again `lrunzip Debian_GNU_Linux_8_jessie_sage-6.8-x86_64-Linux.tar.lrz` gives

```
> Output filename is:
> Debian_GNU_Linux_8_jessie_sage-6.8-x86_64-Linux.tar Decompressing...
> 100%    5625.85 /   5625.85 MB Average DeCompression Speed: 42.939MB/s
> Output filename is:
> Debian_GNU_Linux_8_jessie_sage-6.8-x86_64-Linux.tar: [OK] - 5899130880
> bytes                                 Total time: 00:02:10.73
```

which you can then open by the `ArchiveManager` getting `sage-6.8-x86_64-Linux` -directory as the output.

How can you open such a file .tar.lrz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
$ lrunzip Debian_GNU_Linux_8_jessie_sage-6.8-x86_64-Linux.tar.lrz
```

for which you might have to install `lrzip` first, by doing

```
$ sudo apt-get install lrzip
```

After running `lrunzip` as above, you get a `.tar` archive, which you still need to untar to a directory, for example by running

```
$ tar xvf Debian_GNU_Linux_8_jessie_sage-6.8-x86_64-Linux.tar
```

(or by letting Debian's Archive Manager untar it).

This will produce a directory `Debian_GNU_Linux_8_jessie_sage-6.8-x86_64-Linux` which contains the `sage` executable.

Comment: I added the output after installing the `lrzip` in Debian 8.1 and trying to open the package with `ArchieveManager`. It seems to work only by the terminal command `lrunzip`. The command `lrunzip` somehow binds to `ArchieveManager`.  Do you understand why?

Comment: I expanded my answer to make it clear why the result of `lrunzip` (a `.tar` archive) binds to Archive Manager.

Answer (score 1):

install lrzip as described already

```
sudo apt-get install lrzip
```

then you can use the inbuilt lrzip decompression and untarring wrapper:

```
lrzuntar Debian_GNU_Linux_8_jessie_sage-6.8-x86_64-Linux.tar.lrz
```

which will extract the files in the tar file into a directory called Debian_GNU_Linux_8_jessie_sage-6.8-x86_64-Linux